# What's the name for this sort of join?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to describe a sort of join between two graphs $G$ and $H$ where you delete one edge from each graph (let's call the vertices adjacent to the deleted edges $g_1$, $g_2$, $h_1$ and $h_2$) , and then join the two graphs by adding an edge between $g_1$ and $h_1$, and another between $g_2$ and $h_2$.

Does this join have a special name? I can't seem to find one, although I have a feeling it has one.

Thanks!

Comment: The operation of deleting a pair of parallel edges and replacing them with a disjoint pair arises in the study of graphs with given degree sequence, but even there I do not recall it having a name. (Swapping 2-matchings?)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not sure if this has a name in graph theory, but it reminds me a lot of the [knot sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum#Connected_sum_of_knots) in knot theory.